# How to prevent someone from overriding the code that grabs the windows authentication and uses the username to make wcf calls?

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, windows-authentication, password-protection

Basically, if you use WindowsAuthentication to grab the username, store in a variable and then pass that to any services you use, what's to stop someone from hacking your code and passing in another username?

On the client end you can check the IsAuthenticated, but then after that it only lets you grab the Windows Username, not the Windows password.

Is there some way to just pass that authentication object itself without letting it be hacked? Otherwise, I might have to switch back to not using Windows Authentication as my Authentication and custom rolling a user/pass with a db table.

Comment: If it would be so easy, there wouldn't be any security in windows domains. Just try if you don't believe.

Comment: What makes you think that the username is even used? What makes you think that it's the only thing that's used if it's used at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass user's credentials outside of your server due to "NTLM one hop" behavior. You may be able to configure Kerberos authentication to handle cases when you need user's credentials flow between front end and backend servers.

The other option is to establish trust between servers (i.e. HTTPS with client certificate) so backend server is able to trust user name coming from your server (as it would be the only one with correct client certificate). You will not be able to impersonate the user on backend server as you will on ly have a name.